# Errors on google cloud api - Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception'

Tags: php, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm using Google cloud api.

Following errors make my page blank. Debug log file shows the following errors on loading each blank page.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
' in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php(82): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(Guzz
leHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php(57): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Client.p in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php on li
ne 123

Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Not Found' in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php:123
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php(82): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Object(Guzz
leHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), 'Google_Service_...')
#2 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(181): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php(57): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Client.php(758): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(GuzzleHttp\Client), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)
, 'Google_Service_...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/test/google_api/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 123
```

I think both errors are related. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Not Found'".

Just sharing an error message doesn't help a lot without knowing what it is you're trying to do. All I can say is, whatever you're trying to access, it doesn't exist, at least not where you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). If so you can directly [report this issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues) to the engineers working on this library.

I do see [similar reports](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/718) to this where the solution was a user-end code fix. **'Google_Service_Exception'** indicates that the request you made was either not authenticated, had an invalid/malformed post body, and/or was made to an invalid URL.

Therefore I recommend you attempt to debug your code further in order to see what line of your code is throwing this error. Make sure you are [using the library properly](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started), and that your [API request](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#making-requests) is correct. Also make sure you are using the [latest version](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation) of the library.